# IS optimization unnecessary in SVM?

Tags: svm, optimization, max-margin

According to [here](http://web.mit.edu/6.034/wwwbob/svm-notes-long-08.pdf), Now knowing the $a_i$ we can find the weights $w$ for the maximal margin separating hyperplane:
\begin{align*}
w = \sum_{i=1}^{l} a_i y_i x_i
\end{align*}

I cannot understand what this says. I have trouble in how to choose $a_i$. I think we must conduct Newton-method, Pegasos, SMO, or stuff like that.

In addition, I want to implement hard-margin (linear-separable) SVM in Python. So I am seeking for the most simplest(easiest) optimization method.

I am very grateful to you if you make some answers taking this into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that finding the $a_i$ requires some form of iterative optimization. The thing that doesn't require optimization is converting from the dual variables $a_i$ to the primal variable $w$, which just follows the formula that you wrote.

Comment: It does make sence.Thank you. And as I wrote, I want the most simplest optimization method, then I was wondering if you could give me some ideas?

Comment: If you actually want to use it for something, use an existing library, e.g. scikit-learn's bindings to libsvm. If you want to implement it yourself for learning purposes, stochastic gradient descent is probably simplest.

Comment: SGD is for unconstrain ploblem, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, yeah, you'd have to implement some kind of workaround for the constraints (not sure if you can easily project?). Or you could implement SMO, I don't know how complicated it is (never done it).

Comment: OK. It is difficult for me to implement SMO. But, Thank you.